# How to get data from dialog after i dismiss it?

Tags: java, android, dialog

I have tried to get data from a dialog into a textview but i get the error that the app can t see the textview, because textview is behind dialog...
after i click on button this will appear

```
backpackDialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
backpackDialog.setTitle("Backpack"); 
backpackDialog.setContentView(R.layout.backpack_layout); 
window = backpackDialog.getWindow(); 
lp.copyFrom(window.getAttributes()); 
lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT; 
lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT; 
window.setAttributes(lp); 
backpackDialog.show(); 

// and after i click to dissmis the dialog...
useItemButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{ @Override public void onClick(View view) 
  {  
     // here is the problem...
     intPlayerHealth = intPlayerHealth + 20;
     ->playerHealthText.setText(intPlayerHealth);<-
     backpackDialog.dismiss();
  } 
});
```

how can i go after i dismiss the dialog to restart activity or  something like that to refresh my main activity layout so that way i can get the new value for my textView, and also to not get that error of not being able to see textView, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple written in 
[official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.OnDismissListener)

```java
@Override
public void onDismiss(@NonNull DialogInterface dialog) {
    // here is the problem...
    // You can write you action here
    super.onDismiss(dialog);
}
```

Comment: hi, cannot resolve super.onDismiss... what to do please help me...

Comment: Or just add to your dialog:
```
backpackDialog.getDialog().setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
         @Override
         public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
               //your code
         }
 });
```

Comment: You can add it bettwen:
window.setAttributes(lp); 
//here
backpackDialog.show();

Comment: ohh. try without getDialog().
backpackDialog.setOnDismissListener

Comment: i did it... but it s the same error... after i dismiss the dialog i get the error ndroid.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x78

Comment: textview doesnt refresh

Comment: how can i refresh textview after i dissmis the dialog?

Comment: Did you write ***playerHealthText.setText(intPlayerHealth);*** on dismiss listener?

Comment: yes, intPlayer health integer has the correct value, but textview doesnt refresh it